# Multiple python scripts into a single executable file

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I have 3 python scripts . Two are front-end Gui's and one is a back-end algorithm. These programs run in real time. I want to create an executable that can simultaneously run all the three programs. How can i do that?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Can you help to provide more detail about you question. E.g. what UI framework do you use for your front-end GUI? Do the 3 programs need to interact with each other?

Comment: I am using tkinter for Gui. The three programs are interacting with each other at real time.

Comment: PyInstaller can only freeze one script at a time. So you don't need to freeze multiple scripts, just create one py script that imports other scripts and then freeze it. If you need more help you should add the Minimal working example of your app to your question.